# JTables and Jython Events

Tags: python, event-handling, jtable, jython, actionlistener

I've just been getting started at getting over the hump of swing in Jython vs swing in Java directly.. and I'm wondering if someone can help me out with adding action-listeners to a JTable in Jython.

I know with a button, you can just do:

```
button = Jbutton( " Press me! ", actionPerformed = my.function )
```

and I know that there are different events associated with a JTable.. such as when something is selected, when the focus is changed within the table, when the table itself becomes the focus...

My issue is I don't know how to implement these into the syntax of creating a table.
I create my table with something like the following:

```
data = DefaultTableModel( items, columnNames )
mytable = JTable( data )
```

my basic assumption would be that I need to something like...

```
mytable = JTable ( data, isFocused = my.other.function )
```

but I know not the exact syntax, and the javadocs for JTable are convoluted enough (with the like million other interfaces/classes it implements) let alone when trying to decipher them in a jython context.

Bonus Points:

Beyond just this specific example.. are there any really great resources for syntax of Swing in Jython out there? I've found some stuff but the vast majority seems to have only been sparsely populated and then abandoned. (in terms of documentation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of all possible actions can be found [on this page of the Java Swing tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/api.html).  That page lists all of the listener methods in the third column.  Not all of them will apply to every Swing object, but if it does apply, you can attach a listener just like the `JButton` examples.

You specifically seemed to be looking for a way to notice that the focus was gained by the table.  That is the `focusGained` event, and is described in the [`FocusListener` documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html) which is just off of the first page I mentioned.

Here is your example modified to work:

```
data = DefaultTableModel(items, columnNames)
mytable = JTable(data, focusGained=my.other.function)
```

I'm afraid I couldn't find any good descriptions of Jython Swing work.  Your best bet is probably to adapt examples from the [Swing tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html).  I've always found Sun's documentation to be superb.  (I know, it's Oracle now...)

Let me know if anything is unclear.